# Unable to mount dataset in AzureML notebook getting permission denied error

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataset in AzureML which has 2 CSV files, I am trying to mount this dataset and utilize it in AzureML notebook but corresponding job is getting failed and code throwing permission denied error at `run.wait_for_completion()`

[image]

Below is the AzureML notebook code

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Experiment, Dataset, ScriptRunConfig, Environment

# set workspace
ws = Workspace.from_config()

dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, "<dataset-name>")
compute_target = ws.compute_targets["<compute-name>"]
env = Environment.get(ws, "<environment-name>")
exp = Experiment(ws, "<experiment-name>")

# mount dataset 
input_data = dataset.as_mount()

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory="test",
                    script='test.py',
                    arguments=['--data_folder', input_data],
                    compute_target=compute_target,
                    environment=env)

# submit job
run = exp.submit(config=src)

# monitor run
run.wait_for_completion()
```

***test.py***

```
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import os

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--data_folder", type=str)
args = ap.parse_args()

def main():
    data1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.data_folder, 'file1.csv'))
    data2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.data_folder, 'file2.csv'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any suggestion would be of great help

Comment: Do you happen to have the correct permissions to access that dataset?

Comment: @ewokx I have registered the dataset

Comment: @ewokx how can I see if I have the correct permissions to access that dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved, I had to register the dataset in AzureML with proper configurations